# Can't locate URI/Encode.pm in @INC - Centreon

Tags: perl, monitoring, nagios

```
UNKNOWN: Cannot load module --custommode.
Can't locate URI/Encode.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib/centreon/plugins FatPacked::26594184=HASH(0x195cb88) /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at /usr/lib/centreon/plugins//centreon_office365_management_api.pl line 6867.
```

I'm getting this error when excuting the plugin script although ive URI installed , can anyone please help me with this.. Thanks in advnace.

Comment: What is the output of `perl -MURI::Encode -E 'say $INC{"URI/Encode.pm"}'`

Comment: Can't locate URI/Encode.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .).
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.

Comment: Ok, then I think the module is not installed. Try install it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[URI::Encode](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI::Encode) is a completely different module to [URI](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI). You'll need to install them both separately.